# for a string value how to get "..."

Tags: c#

hello friends i have to get the file name to be displayed in the textbox but the size of it is fixed so i want to get "...." at first and name should be displayed at last..

and here goes my program help me out please...

```
  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         var ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
         ofd.ShowDialog();
        string s = ofd.FileName;

        if (s.Length > 10)
        {
            s = s.Substring(s.Length-10, s.Length);
             textBox1.Text = s;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you make it a label instead of a textbox?

Comment: `textBox1.Text = "..." + s;`, but still you should use textblock / label.

Comment: what ever it may be just i want to get the name of the file irrespective of directories

Comment: Do you want to abbreviate the full path, or do you want to extract the file name?

Comment: i want only name of the file my friends

Comment: Please can you ask that in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you want to show the root + filename instead of this arbitrary abbreviation:

```
string fName = ofd.FileName;
if (fName.Length > 10)
{
    fName = string.Format("{0}...{1}{2}",
                Path.GetPathRoot(fName), 
                Path.DirectorySeparatorChar, 
                Path.GetFileName(fName));
}
textBox1.Text = fName;
```

Answer (score 2):

**Original version of question asked to compact path to fit in a fixed width**

If you want to use the same algorithm as does the shell when it displays shortened file names then you can [p/invoke](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/shlwapi.pathcompactpath) to [`PathCompactPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/bb773575.aspx).

<sub>Of course, you may not wish to p/invoke to Win32 API functions, in which case you'll want another solution.</sub>

**Clarifications in comments indicates that asker merely wants to extract the file name from the full path**

The file name part of a path can be obtained by calling `Path.GetFileName()`.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     var ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
     ofd.ShowDialog();
    string s = ofd.FileName;

    if (s.Length > 10)
    {
        s = s.Substring(s.Length-10, s.Length);
         textBox1.Text = "..." + s;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Everything depends on the font used to display the path. You can have TextBox with the font size 10pt or 32pt. Best way would be to calculate which bit you need to trim off.

Take a look at the solution here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/1acc1d42-416e-4a10-9112-11018e611d95/adjust-file-path?forum=winforms